# Delete Key/Value Pair from configuration file qsetting

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qsettings

i am trying to search String in configuration file and if string match wants to delete key / value pair. i have getting qstringlist from file .
 as far as my tried code is

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        QSettings* settings= new QSettings("/home/sidheshwar/Desktop/temp.txt", QSettings::IniFormat);

        settings->beginGroup("Profiles");
        const QStringList childKeys = settings->childKeys();

        QStringList Keys;
        QStringList values;
        QString user="db-host";
        QString tempUser;


        foreach (const QString &childKey, childKeys)
        {
            Keys << childKey;
            values << settings->value(childKey).toString();
        }

for(int i=0;i< Keys.length();i++){
    if(user == values.at(i)){
         qDebug() << " keys" << Keys[i] << endl;
tempUser=Keys[i];

    }
       qDebug() << " tempUser" << tempUser << endl;


}
      return 0;}
```

how can i use `settings->remove(tempUser);`

Comment: I tried the `remove()` function and I had no problem

Comment: actually its not working for me.. any document link you referred or any code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following example I show you an example of how to delete a data from the file that handles the configuration.

**temp.ini** before the execution.

```
[Profiles]
key1=db-host
key2=value2
key3=value3
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QSettings>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSettings* settings= new QSettings("temp.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);

    settings->beginGroup("Profiles");
    const QStringList childKeys = settings->childKeys();

    QStringList Keys;
    QStringList values;
    QString user="db-host";


    foreach (const QString &childKey, childKeys)
    {
        Keys << childKey;
        values << settings->value(childKey).toString();
    }

    for(int i=0;i< Keys.length();i++){
        if(user == values.at(i)){
            qDebug() << " keys" << Keys[i];
            settings->remove(Keys[i]);
        }
        qDebug() << Keys[i] << values.at(i);
    }


    return a.exec();
}
```

Output:

**temp.ini** after the execution

```
[Profiles]
key2=value2
key3=value3
```